# Why does Count(*) return NULL in ODBC connection to sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

I need to execute a simple sql query on sql server database with ODBC. The sql code is below:

```
insert into mylogint
EXEC(
'select count(*) from mymessage'
)
```

mylogint is a simple table:

```
create table mylogint
(value int)
```

But sometimes I found that table mylogint is empty, because count(*) returned NULL when the ODBC connected a sql server instance. I mean that the count(*) returned NULL rather than int, and I'm sure that mymessage isn't empty. I found that the count(*) returned NULL on some sql instances, returned int on other instances.

Do you know why count(*) returned NULL in this case? What's the possible reason? Thanks.

Comment: count() will never return NULL, if there is nothing to count it returns 0.

Comment: if your table `mylogint`is empty, than either the `insert statement`did not run or an exception occured. It is impossible for a count() to return null that is simply a wrong assumption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count(*)` should never return `NULL`. It is possible for a subquery to return no rows. This could result in what seems like `NULL` values from the subquery, but this is really coming from the lack of rows (an unfortunate confusion in SQL).

Your query has to return one row -- that is how aggregation queries with SQL work.

You are saying that `mylogint` is *empty*. That is very different.  That suggests that you are getting an error when running the query. This could be a permissions error, invalid table name, syntax error, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem was caused by some unicode space symbols in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you

```
 INSERT INTO mylogint
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mymessage
```